# MySQL Query result explanation

Tags: mysql, sql

Pretty straightforward question: Why the output of the following SQL is not null?

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(`FirstName` LIKE 'D%' OR `LastName` LIKE 'D%' OR `City` LIKE 'D%')
AND
(`FirstName` NOT LIKE 'D%' OR `LastName` NOT LIKE 'D%' OR `City` NOT LIKE 'D%')
```

I am using MySQL 5.1. The result is ignoring the "NOT LIKE" part all together.

Comment: Thanks all for your quick reply. Can anybody suggest me how can I change the 'NOT LIKE' part into a 'FULLTEXT' search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `FirstName` that of 'David" then the first parenthetical condition is true.  If you have a `LastName` of "Smith" then the second parenthetical condition is true and your query will return that result.

What you probably mean to be doing is something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE 
(`FirstName` LIKE 'D%' OR `LastName` LIKE 'D%' OR `City` LIKE 'D%')
AND
(`FirstName` NOT LIKE 'D%' AND `LastName` NOT LIKE 'D%' AND `City` NOT LIKE 'D%')
```

(Note the `OR`s that have been changed to `AND`s.)

Answer (score 0):

Change the OR to AND with the NOT LIKE

```
(`FirstName` NOT LIKE 'D%' AND `LastName` NOT LIKE 'D%' AND `City` NOT LIKE 'D%')
```

With the OR if the first condition is true the rest of the condition will not be checked hence you have matching rows there.

Answer (score 0):

FirstName = Arunava
LastName = Dey
City = New York

First part is true cause LastName LIKE 'D%' is true
Second part is true caues FirstName NOT LIKE 'D%' is true
City can be whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You are using OR operator in your conditions. So there is possibility that two different conditions from the above two are true so you will get the result not null.